# data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:theUrl];

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsdata, http-status-code-400

What will happen to the data object if 4xx or 5xx error take place?
Does the program crash? does the data object get any kind of data (response error or corrupted data)? or the data object will be equal to nil?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll get `nil` back.  If you want to know the reason for failure then use:

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:]
```

([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL%3aoptions%3aerror%3a))

Comment: 4xx/5xx is an HTTP Error by all means. Check the W3 RFC: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: @ShaiMishali I know what that means. It doesn't mean the response contains no data. This is something that should be documented.

Answer (score 1):

Referred from [NSData Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

A data object containing the data from the location specified by aURL. Returns `nil` if the data object could not be created.

Answer (score 0):

From client perspective, a 4xx or 5xx is not an error. It is a valid return code that can contain data (stack traces, reason for the error).
You are right the behavior is undocumented. The only way how to know for sure is to test it...

Comment: @trojanfoe But the only way how to know it is to test it... I didn't say what will be returned, I said it is undocumented.